# Copy -Past text with Clipboard

Tags: java, awt, clipboard

I have problem with copy-past action with Clipbord
When I am running application local 192.168.10.88:8080:/... and trying copy paste I got result  ,the text is copied and pasted

When someone else from his computer access to my application 192.168.10.88:8080:/ and try the same there is no text in Clibpord so paste action do not work.
Here is the code:

```
final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
 final SerialTransferable transferable = new SerialTransferable(codeText);
 clipboard.setContents(transferable, null);
```

Do I miss something? How Clipbord works if someone else access me from his computer ?

Comment: Are you using an applet of some kind or is this a web application?  Applets may not have access to the clipboard due to their security restrictions...

Comment: This is web application. jsf + spring Contollers. There is page with example sample code so user instead to select all code and then copy, he can  use copyToClipobordmethod (the code in the question). But only work when I am running application from my pc.

Comment: The copy operation is occurring within the context of your local machine, not the client machine, you'd need to use a JavaScript based solution...